# Laravel 5.5 parametros necessarios para a rota [Route: alimento.show] [URI: alimento/{alimento}]

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new with Laravel and I'm working in a small project for studies purposes!. When I'm accessing `localhost:8000/alimento` show me the following error:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: alimento.show] [URI: alimento/{alimento}]. 
(View: /home/viana/estudo/resources/views/template.blade.php) 
(View: /home/viana/estudo/resources/views/template.blade.php)
```

My codes.

Route:

```
Route::resources([
    'alimento' => 'AlimentoController',
]);
```

Controller:

```
class AlimentoController extends Controller{

    public function index(){
       return view('alimento.index', ['alimentos' => Alimento::get()]);
    }

    public function create(){
       //
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
       //
    }

    public function show(Alimento $alimento){
    //
    }

    public function edit(Alimento $alimento){
    //
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Alimento $alimento){
    //
    }

    public function destroy(Alimento $alimento){
    //
    }
}
```

How do I resolve the error?

Comment: You need to ask in english, or you can go to pt.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to ask in english, but just to answer you:

Seach for "Actions Handled By Resource Controller" in laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers). You're receiving this error because you're calling in your view "alimento.show", but to show something you have to pass the id of this object, after send the alimento to the view, the use `route('alimento.show', $alimento->id)`